# Analysis of PValues Matrix

Tags: p-value, model, matrix, clinical-trials, fraud-detection

in clinical environment I'm setting up a model to identify fraudolent behaviours from specific sites, calculating for each site some aspects that could lead to a p-value (this approach is based on a private tool developed by CluePoint).
Every p-value tries to answer to the question: is the trend for site i, for aspect j, statistically different from the general trend?
Aspects could be for digit preference, inliers detections, etc... (proposed by existing literature).

This is how the matrix looks like.

```
       aspect1  aspect2 ....  aspectj ... aspectk
site1   pval11   pval12 ....   pval1j ...  pval1k
site2   pval21   pval22 ....   pval2j ...  pval2k
...       ....     .... ....     .... ...    ....
sitei   pvali1   pvali2 ....   pvalij ...  pvalik
...       ....     .... ....     .... ...    ....
siten   pvaln1   pvaln2 ....   pvalnj ...  pvalnk
```

But now, I need to create a model, and I can't find way to define an "Y variable", that will be the final risk indicator. 
Any hint?

Comment: I'm a statistical programmer, please just help with theory, not code so I'll implement it in SAS

Comment: Please tell us what you want to determine from this array of p-values.  Note that you might need to adopt very strong (and likely counterfactual) assumptions in order to justify any generic procedure for testing such arrays: at a minimum, you will have to assume the aspects are independent.  It also appears you have no data in this array about actual *risk*, which is ordinarily understood to be a function of the chance of harm and of the amount of harm itself. How, then, do you hope to relate this array to risk?

Comment: Each aspect (each Xi, that is a pvalue) is a risk indicator, if the null hypothesis related to a singular pvalue won't be reject, I assume that that site is conducting a fraudolent behaviour. The fraud-risk of each site (Yi) should be determinated using every aspect (independent as assumption from other aspects) in a model where Yi=f(X1i X2i ...Xki) , also maybe we should add some weights, because we can't set a threshold referred to every values.
Sorry for being this unclear but I'm totally struggling myself too with this task, I'm a statistician but usually working with bigdata.